# How to check if the value exist in string then get the item of value instead just value of true

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have variable like this

```
reg_name = ['aceh', 'sumatera utara', 'sumatera barat', 'riau', 'jambi', 'jakarta']
nama_laut = ['selat sunda', 'laut jawa', 'laut natuna', 'teluk natuna']
txt = 'berita ini berasal dari kota jakarta, tenggelamnya kapal KNKT di perairan selat sunda'
```

and the code like this

```
if any([x in txt for x in nama_laut]):
  print(nama_laut)
else:
  print(reg_name)
```

How can I get only name of value true? for example, based the code above I want to get the value of **"selat sunda"**, but I dont know how get it. Can someone help me? Thanks..

Comment: Don't use `any`, it's solely for getting truthfulness of the values, instead, run a loop and manually check if the value exists, if so, `break` the loop immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just loop over the list and check if its in the text:

```
for word in nama_laut:
    if word in txt:
        print(word)
```

if you have to use a list comprehension:

```
ans = [word for word in nama_laut if word in txt]
print(ans)
```

you can check if the word was present by checking the list:

```
if ans:
   print(ans[0])
else:
   ans = [word for word in reg_name if word in txt]
```

Comment: and what if I dont get nama_laut from txt variable? how can I redirect to variable "reg_name"? for example if word in nama_laut exist in txt I get the value of "selat sunda" if dont, I can get word "jakarta" from variable reg_name

Answer (score 0):

there's a variety of ways to this

using a function is better

```py
def get_name_with_index(txt, list_):
     names = []
     for i, name in enumerate(list_):
         if name in txt:
             names.append((i, name))
     return names
```

```py
get_name_with_index(txt, nama_laut) or get_name_with_index(txt, reg_name)
```

or you can concatenate both lists nd check

```py
# here if you going to use the index, be careful for the length
get_name_with_index(txt, nama_laut+reg_name)
```